# How can I insert the $q provider inside a class that is not wrapped into an angular module?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6, angularjs-scope

I have an es6 module

**MyModule**

```
let _q$;// I would like the $q provider of angularjs to be a private property of that module

export default class MyClass{
   constructor($q){
      _$q = $q
    }
}
```

Actually, the only way (I found) to instanciate MyClass is from an angularjs function:

```
import MyClass from "../model/MyClass";
angular.module('myModule').run(function($q){
   var myObject = new MyClass($q);
})
```

Probleme with it is that I can't access myObject outside current file.

What I would like to do is to instanciate MyClass inside the MyModule, then export it:

```
class MyClass{
   constructor($q){
      _$q = $q
    }
}

export myObject = new MyClass($q);
```

probleme here is that I don't know how to access the $q.

I'm a bit stuck :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full answer is:

```
import angular from 'angular';
const $injector = angular.injector(['ng']);//<- ['ng'] is necessary to tell angular in which module the provider resides.
const $q = $injector.get('$q');

class MyClass {
  someMethod() {
    return $q.resolve('something');
  }
};

export let myObject = new MyClass();
```

Answer (score 1):

When writing standard angularJs code (eg, services, components, or your example with a .run block), the injector is applied automatically for you, but it is possible to invoke it explicitly as well. Something like the following may work for you:

```
import angular from 'angular';
const $injector = angular.injector();
const $q = $injector.get('$q');

class MyClass {
  someMethod() {
    return $q.resolve('something');
  }
};

export myObject = new MyClass();
```

For documentation on the injector, see this page: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector

Comment: I get this error: Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $qProvider <- $q